# Xcode Base Translation: What is Base all about?

Tags: ios, xcode, translation, xliff

I read a lot about Base Translation in Xcode but some parts seem far away from being intuitive or correct.

## localizable.strings

For this question I assume to have an App with base translation and `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion = en`.

### Expected behavior

1) What is inside base translation of `localizable.strings`?

It should be english. So all Apps with a missing translation should fall back to base (=english).

2) What do new translations base upon?

When I export `xliff` files for translation they should source on base translation.

3) Is english needed beside base which is english?

I should not need an english translation, since base is english

### Actual behavior

1) I don't see a use for base translation of `localizable.strings`. It is not used as fallback. It is not used for new translations.

2) xliffs for new languages depend on `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion`, so in this case the english translation. E.g: I export xliff for `fr` -> I get a file which has english translation to work out french translation.

3) To have xliff not to depend on the key in `NSLocalizedString` I need to have a `localizable.strings` in english.

This ends me up in the following.

1) I don't have a base localization for `localizable.strings`

2+3) Instead I need a localization for english and for that I need english as supported language beside `base`.

## XIB/Storyboard

In XIB/Storyboard it is different! I understand that `base` here could be something abstract like "Header Label" or "username" since I can't describe that otherwise.

## All together

I don't need `base`for anything. Instead I need the language of `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` plus each localization I need additionally as translations.

## Questions

1) Is base a concrete language (e.g. english) or an abstract description (e.g. "username")?

2) Do I need the `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` as a concrete localization beside base?

Comment: Well this is quite nice, no answer to such an essential, thouroghly presented question since more than three years. Why is that?

Comment: Thanks @LukeSideWalker, I would still appreciate any answers on that as I still see it open :-)